# Caliper: why not use an annotation to define a benchmark?

Tags: java, microbenchmark, caliper

Just found out about Caliper, and going through the documentation - it looks like a great tool (thanks Kevin and the gang at Google for opensourcing it).

Question. Why isn't there an annotation-based mechanism to define benchmarks for the common use cases? Seems that something like:

```
public class Foo {
  // Foo's actual code, followed by...

  @Benchmark
  static int timeFoobar(int reps) { 
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; ++i) foo.bar(); 
  }
}
```

would save a few lines of code and enhance readability.

Comment: You should probably ask this question in their [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/issues/list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We decided to use `timeFoo(int reps)` rather than `@Time foo(int reps)` for a few reasons:

- We still have a lot of JUnit 3.8 tests and like consistency with its `testFoo()` scheme.
- No need for `import com.google.caliper.Time`
- We'll end up reporting the benchmark name for `time`**Foo** as **Foo**. This is easy, it's just `methodName.substring(4)`. If we used annotations we'd end up with more complicated machinery to handle names like `@Time timeFoo(int reps)`, `@Time benchmarkFoo(int reps)` and `@Time foo(int reps)`.

That said, we're reconsidering this for Caliper 1.0.

Comment: Jesse, thanks for the detailed answer. Your points all make sense, still, as an ex-googler coming from the c++ side of the shop, and having only recently moved java full-time, I have a very fond memory of Sanjay's dead-simple and effective API for C++ microbenchmarks. I used it *a lot* while there for numerical and quasi-numerical code. The annotation syntax just seems the most "natural" to me as it parallels it almost exactly.

Comment: We had a predecessor framework to caliper internally to Google, and it used a @Benchmark annotation, and the main reason we changed it is just the simple reason that I hated it and found the naming convention so much simpler and easier to remember. But yeah, it is not unlikely to change at some point.

Comment: The "time*" convention is IMHO much better: It's simpler and while it's possible to forget to place the annotation you can't forget to name your method appropriately. Please stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that benchmarks that use Annotations cannot be run on pre-Java 1.5 JVMs.  (That's not a very persuasive reason, given how old Java 1.5 is.)

---

Actually this is implausible.  The latest Caliper codebase defines an annotation called `@VmOption` so they can't be aiming to support pre-Java 1.5 platforms.  (Not that I'm suggesting they should ...)